# If -ment suffix is from Old French, then why does it form nouns instead of adverbs?

Tags: etymology, suffixes, derivational-morphology

The suffix *-ment* forms **nouns** from verbs, e.g. *entertain* → *entertain**ment***.

A similar suffix exists in French (and *-mente* in other Romance languages) that forms **adverbs** from adjectives, e.g. *sûr* → *sûre**ment***, which comes from Latin *mentus*.

Is the English noun suffix related to (cognate with) French adverb suffix? If so, then how did it became *v. → n.* from *adj. → adv.*? If not, where does it come from?

Comment: When asking questions about etymology, you should always look up the word you’re asking about on [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com) and include in the question what that tells you. If that sufficiently answers the question, you can delete it; if it doesn’t, add in what remains unclear so we have a ‘sharper’ question to answer. (In this case, note the difference between _-ment_ added to **verbs**, as in English, and _-ment(e)_ added to **adjectives**, as in Romance languages.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks! Didn't know that site before.

Comment: This is an interesting question. Please don’t delete it. If you find the answer yourself, consider posting it as an answer. In case you’re wondering, answering your own questions is not only permitted; Stack Exchange [explicitly encourages it](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: French uses *-ment* both to turn verbs into nouns and adjectives into adverbs. [See Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ment#French).

Comment: French has nouns *établissement* and *divertissement*. So a better question might be why English doesn't use -ment to create adverbs, but instead uses -ly.

Comment: Rapidement in French is an adverb and it ends in -ment.  I'm not sure this question covers all of the possible word forms in French.  -ment is also used with adverbs in French.

Comment: @Karlomanio There may be some, but I cannot think of any; the simplex adverbs I can think of generally do not allow _-ment_, and I’m not sure what the resulting form would mean if they did: _*bienment_, _?vitement_ (exists, but probably formed from the archaic adjective, not the adverb), _*ainsiment_, etc. _Rapidement_ is similarly based on an adjective, not an adverb. If you know of any standard cases of adverb + _-ment_, please share them.

Comment: @Barmar Because the French focus on the mind, whereas the English focus on the body. In a purely etymological way, of course.

Answer (score 1):

First, -ment formed nouns in both Old French and Middle English. For instance, consider the etymology for *garment* (as on [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/garment) and crosschecked with the Oxford English Dictionary or OED).

> c. 1400, "any article of clothing," reduced form of garnement (early 14c.), from Old French garnement "garment, attire, clothes" (12c.), from garnir "fit out, provide, adorn," from a Germanic source (compare garnish (v.)), from PIE root *wer- (4) "to cover."

*Garnement* in Old French (a noun) was formed from a verb + -ment. This kind of formation from Old French *-ment* and Latin *-mentum* has several examples, including the French-derived words *habiliment, abridgement, accomplishment,* and *commencement*, and the Latin-derived words *fragment, aliment,* and *ornament*. (["-ment, *suffix*," OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/116535))

So both French and English allow for the formation of nouns from verbs with *-ment.* What's remarkable is that, from Old French to now, *-ment* could also form adverbs from adjectives, and this *didn't* carry over to English. The *[Oxford Guide to Etymology](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Oxford_Guide_to_Etymology.html?id=l0kTDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q=ment%20mente&f=false)* (2009) summarizes its origin from the Latin ablative phrase '(adjective) mente,' which in English terms served as an adverbial:

> Affixes often result from grammaticalization of adverbs or prepositions. For instance, the adverb-forming suffix *-ment* in French (and likewise Spanish *-mente*, Italian *-mente*, etc.) originates in uses of Latin *mens*, *ment-* in the ablative case in collocations such as *clara mente* 'with a clear mind'. Such collocations showed semantic broadening, e.g. 'clear manner of being or behaving' rather than simply 'with a clear mind', and the pattern became extended to adjectival bases which had no connection with mental activity, ultimately giving rise to a very productive adverb-forming suffix.

Why did the adverb-forming *-ment* not carry over to English while the noun-forming *-ment* did? There's no sure answer, but my training as a medievalist makes a hypothesis tempting. There are a few possible suffixes for forming nouns from verbs in each language because the semantic possibilities are broad, so *-ion* (procession), *-tion* (solution), *-er* (bidder), and others all form nouns from verbs with different senses and limitations; *-ment* fills a place in the Middle English system for aristocratic items as well as functions of government. (See *government*.) That incorporation fits the history of England in that period, which had French-derived legal institutions and a French-speaking aristocracy. Shortly after that point, the suffix was naturalized into English and widely applied to words irrespective of origin. (An early example is *onement*, meaning roughly concord or agreement.)

However, one suffix tends to dominate adverb formation in each language: English has the Old English-derived *-ly* and French has the Old French-derived *-ment*. The suffixes are so widespread and actively used that there is little reason for the suffix to cross over.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ment?ref=etymonline_crossreference:

> -ment
>
> common suffix of Latin origin forming nouns, originally from French
>   and representing Latin -mentum, which was added to verb stems to make
>   nouns indicating the result or product of the action of the verb or
>   the means or instrument of the action. In Vulgar Latin and Old French
>   it came to be used as a formative in nouns of action.